# Float text to right of table cell without losing vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` in a `table` where I want the text in each item to have a left-aligned and a smaller right-aligned part

```
<td><ul>
  <li>Left part <span class="right">right part</span></li>
</ul></td>
```

The problem is that although

```
.right {
  font-size: 80%;
  float: right;
}
```

positions the text correctly to the right edge of the table cell, allowing whatever space needs to be between the left part and right part, this breaks `vertical-align` when the font is shrunk.

I want the left text and right text to be vertically-aligned centrally with respect to each other.

I have played around with `position: relative`, `inline-block`, `text-align`, etc, but nothing I have tried works without side-effects. What's the trick for this?

Comment: make the li display:flex and you have all the options you need

Comment: I tried flex and it put the right part on a new line below the left part.